# My pool drainage seems to break the law of physics

Tags: drainage, pool

I apologise if this is answered somewhere else, but I can't find the answer.

I have an above-ground pool, with an overflow pipe coming out of it about 4" from the top.  This overflow pipe then goes down under the ground, under my garage and comes back up under the house where it has to rise enough to get into a drainage pit.  The height it has to rise to is about 12" below the height at which the pipe exits the pool.

But the water won't rise that high! In fact, it will only rise to about 2 feet lower than it needs to.  I don't understand this.  Shouldn't the water rise to the same level as the pipe exits the pool?  The size of the pipe that goes down from the pool is much smaller than the size of the pipe that comes up from the ground inside the house.  Could this be the reason?

Can anyone point me to somewhere that explains this?  I'm totally stumped - it feels like the laws of physics are breaking.  Could it be that just installing a smaller pipe will allow the water to rise higher?

thanks for any help

Here's a diagram (maybe, need OP to confirm it matches what they intended).  The red line would be the pipe and the blue line inside the red pipe denotes the water level.
[image]

Comment: Are you in Australia?   Does your toilet flush in the other direction?

Comment: Diagram and pictures would be very helpful.

Comment: And how have you verified the outlet is in fact 12" below the outlet? And is there any initial rise right at the inlet?

Comment: Water finds its own level - been used to control heights over distance for hundreds of years. So, check your measurements...

Comment: In the middle of the pipe run there is an additional pair of up and down U bends, partially filled with air.

Comment: Force water through pipe, then check again.

Comment: You think your ground is flat. Observation from over here tells me that it's not, and it actually slopes upwards from your pool to the drainage pit.

Comment: Classic trapped air behavior. If you force water through to remove the bubble(s) it should start flowing again. Siphons can be very picky.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your comments.  I'm really bad at this - I don't know how to answer individual comments, so here's an update for them all!    Our toilets DO flush differently - they have a small amount of water then when you flush it adds more water and then drops down to the original height.  in US I note that flushing reduces the water and then fills back up.  But this is kind of off topic.    I know it's 12" below because the garage floor is level.  the pipe under the house is 2300 above the floor and the top of the pool is 2700 above the floor - then the water is 100 lower.

Comment: continued... all this leaves 300mm fall (12").    I will go and measure it with lasers and confirm, but I've measured this thing so many times, because it really does feel like it breaks physics laws!.   Thank you to Dean for the diagram.  I actually don't know how to add my own.  the only difference I'd say between Dean's diagram and what I'd put there if I could is that the pipe on the right hand side (that comes up from going under the garage) is double the diameter of the one that goes down from the pool.  There are no u-bends under the garage - it's a straight pipe (it's covered in...

Comment: ...concrete now, but I saw it when it was laid.    I have forced water through from the pool side by sticking a hose in it...so there shouldn't be any air-bubbles.  when I pull the hose out, some water flows back into the pool until the same level is reached inside again....ACTUALLY - THAT TRIGGERS AN IDEA - I'm going to fill the pipe up more from inside and see if it flows into the pool from (I can't believe I'm saying this!) the lower height inside????    By the way - it's not a syphon - the pipe doesn't go up above the pool level and back down again - it stays below all the way across.

Comment: thanks for everyone's patience.  I'd say all the responses confirm that water should reach the same height and there's not some rule about different heads of water depending on the thickness of the pipe.  It's really appreciated.

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler: on what basis are you making that statement? Or are you just speculating?

Comment: do you mean the statement that the responses confirm the water should reach the same height regardless of pipe diameter?  I wasn't speculating as much as interpreting.  This is my understanding of what people are telling me.  I'm open to other comments, but did think this is what people have said.

Answer (score 0):

It is sort of a siphon and you have a problem common to siphons , air lock. Air pockets interrupt water flow. You can pump water into the pipe to push out the air but unless you have a constant flow of water ,air will get in again. The U bends you refer to in comments are likely the main problem. With no air ,the water levels at each end of the pipe will be exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't have u-bends, but I'll work on trying to get rid of air in the line.

Comment: How large is this pipe and at what elevation do you live at?